# Setting up onclick handlers into for

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array  `this.conds = ["addr", "acc"]`  for example. I have all these `DOM` objects in html tree. All for this piece of code:

```
     for(cond in this.conds) {

        this.searchBy[this.conds[cond]] = {
            "btn": $("#" + this.conds[cond] + "Btn"),
            "fields": $("#" + this.conds[cond] + "Fields"),
            "active": false
        };

        // Handlers
        __THIS = this;
        this.searchBy[this.conds[cond]].btn.click(function() {

            __THIS.setAllUnactive();
            __THIS.searchBy[__THIS.conds[cond]].active = true;
            __THIS.searchBy[__THIS.conds[cond]].fields.show();

        });

    }
```

I cant  make handler to handle current element of `this.conds`. It handle last element every time. How to avoid this wrong behavior?

Comment: why cant you use simple loop construct ,`for(cond=0;cond<this.conds.length;cond++) {..}`

Comment: `cond` before handler has numeric value (indexes of `this.conds` array), but inside handler `cond` has string value (values of `this.conds` array). How??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common JavaScript pitfall. JS doesn't have *block context*; any variables you set in a block go up to the surrounding context. You have a few options here:

1. Use `$.each()` to loop, as it takes a function, and consequently keeps context.
2. Use `[].forEach()`, which is similar to `$.each()`, but native JS. (Note: not available in older browsers.)
3. Wrap each iteration in a function, like this

`function handleCond(cond) {
// put all that code here
}
for(cond in this.conds) {
    handleCond(this.conds[cond]);
}`

I should note that it's better not to use a `for...in` loop for arrays. Use `$.each()` or `for (i=0;i<list.length;i++)` instead.

EDIT: In option 3, remember to switch `this.conds[cond]` to plain `cond`.

Comment: Thanks! (3) works well. But other 2 will be useful too!